# Проверка целостности бэкапа PostgreSQL 9.2

Tags: linux, postgresql

Интересует вопрос можно ли как-то проверить правильность/целостность созданного бэкапа, при том не востанавливая его.

Т.е. после создания бэкапа утилитой `pg_dump` ночью. Утром проверить всё ли корректно записалось и его можно востановить без ошибок. Есть ли какая-нибудь утилита для этого?

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/13719108/how-to-verify-that-an-archive-produced-by-pg-dump-archive-is-ok-and-valid

Comment: Не нашел ответа на свой вопрос. Каким способом можно проверить целостность НЕ востанавливая бэкап?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если `pg_dump` завершился с кодом возврата 0 и не писал что-либо в `stderr` - значит дамп создан корректно и скорее всего вы сможете из него восстановиться.

Я написал "скорее всего" потому что это общее правило ведения бекапов: вы не можете быть уверены, что можете восстановиться из бекапа не попробовав восстановиться из этого бекапа.

PS: 9.2 уже давно EOL, рекомендую запланировать обновление.

Comment: Хороший совет. А как понять или как мне вывести сообщение с каким кодом возврата завершился `pg_dump`?

Comment: В bash код возврата последней команды доступен из переменной  `$?`, `echo $?` в частности. Для других интерпретаторов нужно уточнять.

Comment: Думаю это решит мою проблему.